# Weirdest Use Of Sound

Tags: weird

[youtube]DanOeC2EpeA[/youtube]

[DARPA Demos Acoustic Suppression of Flame](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DanOeC2EpeA)

Just saw this video demo of the Defence Advanced Research Projects Agency's (DARPA) Instant Fire Suppression program.

Pretty crazy right?

So what's the weirdest use of sound you've come across?

Answer (score 2):

The use of ultrasonic frequencies to generate localized, audible, sound: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19574137

Using inaudible sound waves to recreate audible sound somewhere else? It's basically holographic sound. I talked to a guy at AES in 2011 who works on that kind of thing over in Europe, and it completely blew my brain apart. The technology ain't young by any stretch. It's part of how [Audio Spotlight](http://www.holosonics.com/) works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Ultrasonic levitation : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4exO4CuoSU

Cymatic Studies http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY6z2hLgYuY

http://cuneimedia.com/culture/pharmaceutical-research-yields-acoustic-levitation

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/science/2012/02/converting-light-to-sound-in-cold-quantum-systems/

Comment: @Shaun Farley: thanks for the infos about Holographic sound ... very interesting.